# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory when training Keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, theano, ioerror

I have been having some issues with training my sequential model in Keras. I am new to the subject, therefore there is a lot of following tutorials and code snippets involved...

I was building a basic CNN to distinguish between linear infrastructure and geomorphological features on the basis of orthophotos. Since the images are very huge, I had to create a data generator which was following the Keras Docs. 
The compilation of the model works fine. But every time I run the model.fit_generator() command I get the error, that one of my training images is missing (which it is not). I set five epochs to start, the error already occurs in the first one.

I am thankful for any ideas what might have gone wrong.

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, with an iypthon notebook, theano backend.

```
train_path = '/path/to/train/folder'
tree_top = os.listdir(train_path)
training_filenames = os.listdir('%s/%s/' %(train_path, tree_top[0])) + os.listdir('%s/%s/' %(train_path, tree_top[1]))

valid_path = '/path/to/valid/folder'
tree_top = os.listdir(valid_path)
valid_filenames = os.listdir('%s/%s/' %(valid_path, tree_top[0])) + os.listdir('%s/%s/' %(valid_path, tree_top[1]))
```

Data Generator

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np

class MY_Generator(Sequence):    # inherits from Sequence class 

    def __init__(self, image_filenames, labels, batch_size):
        self.image_filenames, self.labels = image_filenames, labels
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):    # computes number of batches by dividing sample size by the batch_size
        return np.ceil(len(self.image_filenames) / float(self.batch_size))
        num_training_samples = len(self.image_filenames)
        return num_training_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.image_filenames[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.labels[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)


my_training_batch_generator = MY_Generator(training_filenames, tree_top, batch_size)
my_validation_batch_generator = MY_Generator(valid_filenames, tree_top, batch_size)
```

The convnet

```
model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(300,400,3)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(2, activation='softmax'),
    ])
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(generator=my_training_batch_generator,
                                          steps_per_epoch=(len(my_training_batch_generator.image_filenames) // batch_size),
                                          epochs=5,
                                          verbose=1,
                                          validation_data=my_validation_batch_generator,
                                          validation_steps=(len(my_validation_batch_generator.image_filenames) // batch_size)
                                          )
```

The Output is as follows:

> Epoch 1/5
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         4                                           verbose=1,
>         5                                           validation_data=my_validation_batch_generator,
>   ----> 6                                           validation_steps=(len(my_validation_batch_generator.image_filenames)
>   // batch_size)
>         7                                           )
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.pyc in
>   wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>        89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
>        90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
>   ---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>        92         wrapper._original_function = func
>        93         return wrapper
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in
>   fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose,
>   callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch) 
>   1416             use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,    1417
>   shuffle=shuffle,
>   -> 1418             initial_epoch=initial_epoch)    1419     1420     @interfaces.legacy_generator_methods_support
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.pyc
>   in fit_generator(model, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose,
>   callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, class_weight,
>   max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
>       179             batch_index = 0
>       180             while steps_done < steps_per_epoch:
>   --> 181                 generator_output = next(output_generator)
>       182 
>       183                 if not hasattr(generator_output, '**len**'):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.pyc in
>   get(self)
>       599         except Exception as e:
>       600             self.stop()
>   --> 601             six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
>       602 
>       603
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.pyc in
>   get(self)
>       593         try:
>       594             while self.is_running():
>   --> 595                 inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
>       596                 self.queue.task_done()
>       597                 if inputs is not None:
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
>       565             return self._value
>       566         else:
>   --> 567             raise self._value
>       568 
>       569     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DJI_0168.JPG'